# Poincaré dual of the trivial class $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^5,\mathbb{Z}_2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, projective-space

Let $$a \in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^5,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2,$$

- When $a' \in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^5,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a nontrivial generator, the Poincaré dual (4-manifold generator) PD$(a')$ of the nontrivial class $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^5,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is $\mathbb{RP}^4$  in $\mathbb{RP}^5$ (Yes?).

> - When $a \in H^1(\mathbb{RP}^5,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, what is the Poincaré dual (4-manifold generator) PD$(a)$ of the trivial class $H^1(\mathbb{RP}^5,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ in $\mathbb{RP}^5$? Can it be $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

Comment: Arun Debray’s comment to your question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309604/non-spin-5-manifold-and-22-bockstein-homomorphism answers your (first) question.

Comment: "Poincaré dual for 0∈H1(M;ℤ/2) is any embedded closed 4-manifold which bounds" - it means that $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is also OK, but it looks too general to be true to me -- that is why I asked.

Comment: @wonderich: $\mathbb{CP}^2$ does not bound.

Comment: If I am correct, $\mathbb{CP}^2=S^{5}/S^1$, why $\mathbb{CP}^2$ does not bound? (You mean  $\mathbb{CP}^2$  does not bound a point or a line or what?) Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^2$ cannot be the boundary of a compact five-dimensional manifold with boundary; i.e. $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is not nullcobordant. One way to see this is that it has odd Euler characteristic, whereas every manifold which bounds (i.e. is nullcobordant) has even Euler characteristic. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1385734/39599) for more details.