# $RP^2$ as a boundary of a 3-manifold

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Can anyone explain why $RP^2$ is not a boundary of any 3-manifold?

I observe that getting of nonorientable 3-manifold by handle attaching is possible only when attaching 1-handle with orientation preserving and reversing in boundaries of 1-handle. But I don't how to use this to prove this question.
If it is not possible to prove using this, please explain why.

Thanks, advance.

Comment: Because the Euler characteristic of the boundary of a compact manifold is even (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99898/39599)) but $\chi(\mathbb{RP}^2) = 1$.

Comment: This is false without extra conditions such as the compactness condition in the comment of @MichaelAlbanese: $RP^2$ is the boundary of the 3-manifold $RP^2 \times [0,\infty)$.