# Any 3 manifold can be realized as a boundary of a 4 manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

It was mentioned in [Topological gauge theories and group cohomology,
Robbert Dijkgraaf, Edward Witten,
Comm. Math. Phys. 129(2): 393-429 (1990).](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-129/issue-2/Topological-gauge-theories-and-group-cohomology/cmp/1104180750.full)

> Any 3 dimensional manifold can be realized as the boundary of a 4 dimensional manifold. (In page 2 (labeled 394)).

It seems that there are some unstated assumptions given here. [The paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-129/issue-2/Topological-gauge-theories-and-group-cohomology/cmp/1104180750.full) may mean that the 3-manifold is orientable. My questions:

1. What are assumptions?

- orientable or non-orientable?
- compact or non-compact?
- smooth differentiable or not?

2. How to prove: Any 3 dimensional manifold (with what assumptions) can be realized as the boundary of a 4 dimensional manifold.

How does it apply to for example $\mathbf{RP}^2 \times S^1$?

I find some related questions, but I still hope someone can provide new and easier answers than these:

[$RP^2$ as a boundary of a 3-manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357638/rp2-as-a-boundary-of-a-3-manifold)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63373/elegant-proof-that-any-closed-oriented-3-manifold-is-the-boundary-of-some-orien

[Any N dimensional manifold as a boundary of some N+1 dimensional manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685531/any-n-dimensional-manifold-as-a-boundary-of-some-n1-dimensional-manifold)

Comment: There's an awful lot of information in [this link you included](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63373/elegant-proof-that-any-closed-oriented-3-manifold-is-the-boundary-of-some-orien). Did you look carefully at any of the proofs mentioned there to see if they might satisfy your requirements for an "easy answer"? Part of the reason I ask is that the proofs mentioned in that link include some of the most modern proofs.

Comment: I skim through it. What I concern is whether the statement in Comm. Math. Phys. 129(2): 393-429 (1990) paper is more general than the closed orientable assumption used in other MO post. :) I hope someone can confirm this MUST be the assumption in the witten paper

Comment: The question is what you mean by "is a boundary". If you mean "there is a 4-manifold whose boundary is the given 3-manifold $M$", then the answer is trivial by just taking $M\times[0,1)$. This is why one usually talks about the non-trivial question of whether a given manifold is the boundary of a *compact* manifold, but this of course only is a meaningful question if the manifold we started with is compact. Usually, these problems are stated and solved in the smooth category, but for 3-manifolds, this is a non-assumption by [Moise's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moise's_theorem).

Comment: Regarding orientability vs. non-orientability, is is both true that a compact (not necessarily oriented) 3-manifold is the boundary of some compact 4-manifold and that an oriented, compact 3-manifold is the oriented boundary of some oriented compact 4-manifold (which is a stronger statement). The relevant term to look up here is "(oriented) cobordism".

Comment: $\bf RP^2\times D_2$